# Is it possible to trigger a schedule job manually without duplicating the workflow in GitHub Github actions?

Tags: github-actions

I am kinda new to github actions and I'm curious to know whether is it possible to trigger schedule job manually without duplicating the workflow yaml.

```
name: Build Automation
on:
  workflow_dispatch
  schedule:
    - cron: 0 1 * * *
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:   
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.5.0
      - name: Dependency Installation
        run: npm install
      - name: Schedule Execution
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4.2.0
        with: 
          install: true
          command: npm start
      - name: Upload Test Artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3.1.0
        with:
          name: dist
          path: dist/
          retention-days: 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workflow is missing a colon here

```
name: Build Automation
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: 0 1 * * *
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:   
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.5.0
      - name: Dependency Installation
        run: npm install
      - name: Schedule Execution
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4.2.0
        with: 
          install: true
          command: npm start
      - name: Upload Test Artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3.1.0
        with:
          name: dist
          path: dist/
          retention-days: 7
```